# Offscreen Text of menu experiences delay when scrolled into view - WebView issue ? (iOS)

Tags: ios, sqlite, menu, webview, loading

I have a large drilldown menu in my iOS app. 
The menu content originated from XML. 
It's stored in an SQLite database and Webview is being to used. 
Why is Webview being used? Because the text has styling (font size/ color).

Here's the problem: When you scroll down the menu, the text bars that were previously offscreen remain invisible for a 1/2 second. They're taking awhile to load. And you scroll up again, the top items that were moved off screen now take time to appear as well.

Is there a way to improve this performance when working with WebView?  Is there anyway to eliminate this visual loading time?  Are there approaches we should consider? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you putting web views inside of a `UITableView`? You really can't do that; they'll fight each other (and this is explicitly documented as not supported).

There are two main solutions: redesign this part of the program as a web app, or layout with Core Text. Doing all the work in a single `UIWebView` is much faster, but requires moving between JavaScript and Objective-C which is difficult to develop and debug. If you go this way, I generally recommend that you build the JavaScript part as a "mini-app" that you can develop and debug in Safari, and then drop-in.

For simple layout, Core Text isn't too hard. If you create a `CFAttributedString`, here's all you need to draw a very simple frame:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
  if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
    CGAffineTransform 
    transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1);
    CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 
                               0,
                               -self.bounds.size.height);
    self.transform = transform;
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  }
  return self;
 }

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformIdentity);

  CGPathRef path = CGPathCreateWithRect(self.bounds, NULL);

  CFAttributedStringRef
  attrString = (__bridge CFTypeRef)self.attributedString;

  // Create the framesetter using the attributed string
  CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(attrString);

  // Create a single frame using the entire string (CFRange(0,0))
  // that fits inside of path.
  CTFrameRef
  frame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter,
                                   CFRangeMake(0, 0),
                                   path, 
                                   NULL);

  // Draw the frame into the current context
  CTFrameDraw(frame, context);

  CFRelease(frame);
  CFRelease(framesetter);
  CGPathRelease(path);
}
```

And the required plug: Yes, my book will include over 20 pages on all kinds of fancy text layout, mostly using Core Text (just finishing that chapter today). But for the simple stuff the above is enough, as long as you don't need cut and paste.

Comment: Thanks so much Rob. We will look into this. Do you think the Core Text approach is viable even with a very large drilldown menu, which is what this is?   The source XML is going to be 10MB, I anticipate.

Comment: Core Text is the lowest-level text layout engine in Cocoa. It's the fastest system available. For something I think would work well with this problem, see https://github.com/Cocoanetics/NSAttributedString-Additions-for-HTML